# Flutter shows CachedNetworkImage error when run the app, i have used NetworkImage instead of CachNetworkImage?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, networkimageview, flutter-packages

On run the flutter app in Android Studio shows weird error of `CacheNetworkImageProvider`, even though i didn't used it.
the compile message is :

```dart
  BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius:
    new BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
    image: DecorationImage(
        image: NetworkImage(
            featuredcontent[index].images),
        fit: BoxFit.cover),
  ),
```

compiler message:

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-1.1.3/lib/src/cached_network_image_provider.dart:42:24: Error: The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(CachedNetworkImageProvider key) {
                       ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:574:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').
  ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: please post your code. Sometimes you have to stop debugging and start debugging again when you change your pubspec.yaml

Comment: @Uni I have edited the post,Please Help.

Comment: try running flutter clean @Sunil Sharma Sometimes your ui wont be updated by flutter. One time, I had to to flutter clean everytime to see the changes

Comment: What is the output of `featuredcontent[index].images` is it one value or many?

Comment: @dev-aentgs it's one value,actually its the List

Comment: @Uni my flutter clean gives error;
Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself. To find and stop such a program, see: https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used

Comment: @SunilSharma If you are using Windows, you can use taskmanager to stop the program. You simply have to stop dart and the phone emulator you are using.

Comment: @SunilSharma `NetworkImage( )` expects only one `URL` as input parameter. 
If the value returned by `featuredcontent[index].images` is a `list` then `NetworkImage( )` wont be able to resolve.

Comment: @dev-aentgs I have ListView builder, if not to use NetworkImage(),then what's the alternative.

Comment: @SunilSharma access inidividual image `URL` from the list using the index `featuredcontent[index].images[index]`

Comment: @dev-aentgs it not helps

Comment: @Uni it's not working

Comment: @SunilSharma Just for testing, replace `featuredcontent[index].images` by this `'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'` and re-run

Comment: @dev_aentgs this error not have concern with Image,i have just put Text widget instead of Image,still getting same error.

Comment: Search this in Google @SunilSharma The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'. https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/270 and https://github.com/johnpryan/flutter_map/issues/472 popped out